# GRANT privileges to an admin named record in postgreSQL

Tags: admin, record, postgresql-9.3, privileges, sql-grant

I am maintaining an Audit Log. I have like 1100 tables in my database. Problem is that I'd like to use triggers to store also the id of user who made those changes. And by id I mean id from node js application, not PostgreSQL user id. I am using PostgreSQL 9.3. Please provide the necessary help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tables is named 'users' which has an 'admin named record' to whom I wish to give all the privileges?..

Comment: Yes exactly...Table_name=users and it has an 'admin named record'.

Comment: sorry - I'm not aware of `admin named record` feature. Maybe try rephrasing your post?..

Comment: I have tried to re-frame my query. If possible please provide necessary help.